# How to order articles within a category?

Tags: joomla2.5

**Problem:** I have some articles within the same category. in the field `ordering`, some articles have the same number:

[image: screenshot articles-list]

As in the picture, I can't control which one of the two articles with `ordering = 0` goes up.

**Question**: How to get unique ordering-numbers to accomplish decent ordering?

I tried moving the articles to a new category, but they didn't change their order-numbers.

Comment: What number? Article IDs will always be unique. And where are you doing this sorting? In code? In a menu item?

Comment: @isherwood the number in the `ordering`-column. I do the sorting in the backend in the articles-list. The menu-item is set to category-blog, `blog-layout-options | article-sorting = article-ordering` --> shows the articles in the order defined in the backend articles-list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @isherwood pointed out, check how the ordering is set in the menu link.

You mention that it is by article ordering so now
- go to content > article manager

- at the top of the article table, click **ordering**
- change the **numbers** for each article as required (or use the up / down arrows)
- click the **save** icon

Good luck

[image]

Comment: This is what I want to do, however two articles share the same number in the ordering column and I don't know how to fix that. I updated my question with a screenshot, please take a look.

Comment: @michi , don't worry about articles currently having the same numbers. Change 0-0-1-1-2-2 to say 6-5-4-3-2-1 , save and you will be good to go